# Cannot find name 'sendResponse'

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(props) {
switch(props) {
case props.request_type = 'msg':
websocketClass.msgSubmit(props.data)
break;
case props.request_type = 'url':
websocketClass.msgSubmit(props.data)
break;
case props.request_type = 'his':
sendResponse({his: websocketClass.messages});
        }
    }
);
```

I have an issue where, although I have @types/chrome added, sendResponse still returns the above error. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sendResponse` is not a global symbol, it's a parameter of the listener but you specified only `props`, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).
2. `switch` will never match, it only overwrites `request_type` with values ('msg', 'url', 'his').

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  switch (msg.request_type) {
    case 'msg':
    case 'url':
      websocketClass.msgSubmit(msg.data);
      break;
    case 'his':
      sendResponse({ his: websocketClass.messages });
    case 'foo':
      callFunctionThatReturnsPromise(msg).then(sendResponse);
      // Keeps the internal channel open for sendResponse after this listener exits.
      // Only use `return true` if you really invoke sendResponse asynchronously.
      return true;
  }
});
```